# make vagrant development box accessible over internet for customer review

Tags: vagrant, noip

I am trying to make my vagrant box accessible over internet for quick customer review. I tried to get it working over `noip` but somehow it did not work and I don't even know why. My networking knowledge is quite beginner level and now even more confused.

Do I have to use vagrants bridged network option to do that ?

How would you do that. Should be pretty common to allow access for that purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[vagrant share](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/share/) is the feature you're looking

> Vagrant Share allows you to share your Vagrant environment with anyone
>   in the world, enabling collaboration directly in your Vagrant
>   environment in almost any network environment with just a single
>   command: `vagrant share`.

Just make sure you dont tie your webserver to `localhost` or the hostname as vagrant will give you a temporary url to access the instance

Comment: Oh my god :D completely missed that point .... now I remeber reading about that option ... some time ago. Great I try to get that working. Thank you